# Jquery UI 1.9 breaks Asual address plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Im using jQuery v1.8.2 and I just updated from jQuery UI 1.8.17 to 1.9 and the address plugin from https://github.com/asual/jquery-address doesnt work anymore.

This is what I have

```
$.address.change(function(event) {
    $("#tabs").tabs("beforeActivate", window.location.hash)     
});
$("#tabs").bind("tabsactivate", function(event, ui) {
    window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;
});
```

I get an error on the consolog log

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined
```

I cant seem to find the root of the problem. Could anyone help me find out what jquery 1.9 changed, because ive been reading docs and cant figure it out how to fix(update) it.

Thanks

EDIT: I replace ui.tabs.has with ui.newTab.hash and now it get an #undefined hash

Comment: You can just check the changelog of jQuery and see if some of the changes break old behavior. Thats what i do when i want to update my jQuery version. Problem is that its not an purpose of jQuery to keep old api behaviors stable. (thats also the reason why i havn't updated my jQuery from 1.6.1 to a newer one)

Comment: what I did its just replace the new tab section of the script with the old one as well as the css. And it works. They did some massive changes to the tab section and its really hard to find outs whats breaking the plugin

Answer (score 1):

In 1.9.0 they changed the behaviour of tabs when a `<base>` tag is present in the tabs page:

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8637

and it looks like they think it is a feature, not a bug:

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7822

You could however experiment removing/adding a `<base>` tag in your page.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because of deprecated $.browser.
https://github.com/asual/jquery-address/issues/166